# android cardview margin bottom is greater than top by default

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

**Issue:** 
By using cardview in recycler view, it is taking default margins for top and bottom.
[Issue Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCo6s.jpg)

how to maintain same margin for both?

here's my xml of card layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cardcolor"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

        ..//body    

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

My Recycler view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomePageActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @PiyushGupta i added it recently by going reference here on site. it has no effect still even after removing.

Comment: Just give padding of 5dp in you RecyclerListView then you see complete items have same padding of 10dp

Comment: And also changed margins of cardview right?

Answer (score 0):

In your rowitem do as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/cardcolor"
android:marginTop="2.5dp"
android:marginBottom="2.5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false" >

    ..//body    

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

And give margin to your recyclerview in parent layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
layout_marginBottom="2.5dp"
tools:context=".HomePageActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry and thanks but still the layout is as it is. i added margin bottom in recycler view and android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" in card layout but same.

Comment: I hope you are not adding any other margins and padding to your recyclerview and its parent layout except marginBottom right?

Comment: check my edited Q (recycler view) where i did exactly as you said.

Comment: Thank you All guys. with all your help i solved it by adding   android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" in card view linear layout and   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" in recycler view. its in question (edited)